# Hipaa - doctor shared my medical information with everyone at religious facility

Tags: hipaa

I went to the emergency room in March thinking I had Covid-19 and since I am young and healthy the doctors labeled me as having a panic attack and assumed I was on something and so they drew blood for a blood test and quickly found out I was on nothing and they gave me some prescription for coughing and the cold and sent me on my way. It turns out one of the emergency room doctors that looked at my blood sample goes to the same religious facility as me and he told everyone there about what had happened and people have been treating me significantly different and it wasn't until someone revealed that the doctor told everyone this. My question is, shouldn't this be a violation of hipaa? I thought doctors aren't supposed to share any sort of medical information with anyone?

Location - Dallas, TX.

What course of actions should I take?

What course of actions can I take?

Comment: I don't know if this disclosure violates HIPAA, but it surely violates the physician-patient privilege, at least in the US. The doctor could be subject to civil (not criminal) liability and damages, as well as professional discipline from whatever government authority licenses doctors in that jurisdiction.

Answer (score 4):

Gossiping about a patients medical information is a clear violation of the privacy rule, and significant enough that various HIPAA-compliance websites list this in their "10 things for medical professional not to do".

Comment: _Especially_ with somebody's NAME attached to it, good grief! At the very least, file a formal complaint and get that doctor hauled in front of the board of ethics.